# WPF : Measure data binding time consumption

Tags: wpf, performance, binding

How to measure the data binding time consumption alone in WPF application.

Comment: What is data binding time consumption?

Comment: How much time requires to resolve all the data binding belongs to one UIElement

Comment: quick tips for optimizing binding performance, can be found  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `performance profiling tools` in order to mesure

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx

Comment: These tools contain exactly nothing for measuring binding performance. Rendering, layouting - sure